# Retrive username of the loged in user using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retreve the username of the logedin user and based on that take different actions.

I tried using `$the_user = wp_get_current_user()` but I get, not defined error.

Than i found this post [wp_get_current_user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58429/how-do-i-call-wp-get-current-user-in-a-plugin-when-plugins-are-loaded-before-p) and added the following code on functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'get_user_info' );

function get_user_info(){
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

  if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) 
    return; 

  echo $current_user->user_login;

  // Do the remaining stuff that has to happen once you've gotten your user info
}
```

My question is, at this point, how can I retreve the username of the logedin user using jquery??

ps: I have installed custom_css_js plugin

Comment: what is the `custom_css_js` plugin? You need to put the username/information somewhere on the page/frontend, that way you can then select it using jQuery. The code in your question runs far too early

Comment: `custom css & js` Just enables to add js code on an easy way. 

Actually i want to do an easy task. 
After the the user is logged in, based on the username i would like to show customs informations.
The problem is that i can not find a way to get the username of the logged in person...

Comment: like I said, you need to insert that information on to the page somewhere that jQuery can find it, e.g. in a variable or on a tag attribute etc. `plugins_loaded` is far far too early, anything you print there will be shown before the opening HTML tag, and will even be printed on pages that are not the frontend, such as WP Admin or RSS feeds etc

Comment: Tried this 
`add_action( 'get_header', 'get_user_info' );` but still no luck

Comment: How are you testing it? The code in your question just prints it out, but doesn't put it in a tag or a javascript variable, and `get_header` is still too early ( it fires before the header is printed so you would still get weird broken HTML, that's not how you insert tags into the `<head>` via filters ). Do you have javascript that you've not shared that tries to grab the username from the page? It needs to be inside a tag or in a tags attribute so that you have something to tell jQuery to search for, I'm not seeing anything like that in your code

Comment: @TomJNowell
Probably i am doing it all wrong. So lets make it simple. Is there any way I can save on a variable the username of the logged in user using jquery?